# Conversion from string to datetime not being done automatically by CLR

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

I have to retrieve value of label containing date and compare it with current date. I tried converting its value to date first then formatting, but it is not working. I used `CDATE`, `Convert.datetime` and `CTYPE`. But each one is giving same result. My code is as below:

```
Dim datevoucher As DateTime = Format(CType(lblDate.Text, DateTime), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

I am getting below error :

```
Conversion from string "05/31/2009" to type 'Date' is not valid
```

In my case `lblDate.text = "05/31/2009"`

I also tried as below, but still showing error as `" cannot convert string to datetime."`

```
Dim datevoucher As DateTime = Format(DateTime.Parse(lblDate.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

I tried also using culture like below, but again not successfull, it worked initially, but then it abruptly started throwing error on it also. I changed nothing at all in code :

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(lblDate.Text,
             System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat)
```

From last two days, I have tried everything I could find on internet, but problem is persisting.

Comment: try `DateTime.ParseExact(lblDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", Nothing)`

Comment: I resolved issue, but I feel your is better. WIll try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why this is not working

```
Dim datevoucher As DateTime = Format(CType(lblDate.Text, DateTime), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

because

- `Format()` will produce an output in string format it is not directly cast to the `DateTime` format. that's why you are getting the error
- Text is also cannot be converted to dateTime format.
  Here i proposed you `[CDate][1]` for this conversion

For **example** :

```
    Dim s As String = "05/31/2009"
    Dim mydate As DateTime = CDate(s)
```

for **your scenario**:

```
Dim datevoucher As DateTime = CDate(lblDate.Text)
```